# Axis of a plot with quarters and year

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im working with time series given in quarter in R and I want to make a graph as follows:

[image]

I have search all over the internet but I haven't get any answer

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get good help fast, you will need to provide more information. Please follow the instructions for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a time series object like this:

```r
d <- ts(c(265, 280, 288, 280, 278, 292, 298, 282), start = 2016, frequency = 4)

d
#>      Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
#> 2016  265  280  288  280
#> 2017  278  292  298  282
```

Then you could get a reasonable replica of the plot by doing:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(date = time(d), SALES = d) |>
  within(year <- floor(date)) |>
  within(Quarter <- paste0("Q", date %% 1 * 4 + 1)) |>
  ggplot(aes(interaction(Quarter, year), SALES, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 2, color = "#497dba") +
  scale_y_continuous("PRICE (millions)", labels = scales::dollar,
                     breaks = 24:31 * 10, limits = c(240, 310)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, labels = ~sub("\\.", "\n", .x)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there any way to display only one label per year like in the graph in the original question?

Comment: @r-newbie yes, but not easily. You would need to draw the text and line segments on as new layers. It would only take a few lines of code, but there's no out-of-the-box ggplot solution.